# How to group concat based on where condition?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to show all transaction that occurs in a date( as like. 12-12-12, 15-9-20).

now it is showing each transaction in separate div. but I want to show all transaction that occurs same day in same div. As linke I have five transaction in 12-12-12.

```
mysql> select * from all_trans;
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| row_id | user_id | trans_date | debit      | credit       | other      |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|      1 |      30 | 2015-11-09 | vcvv#      | dfdsfsd#     | df+-       |
|      2 |      30 | 2015-11-09 | tertreter# | tferterte#   | gdfgdf+-   |
|      3 |      25 | 2012-12-12 | 2000#      | 200#         | dfsdfsd+   |
|      4 |      30 | 2015-11-16 | dffdfgd#   | dfsdfdsfds#  | fsdfsd+c   |
|      5 |      30 | 2015-11-16 | dffdfgd#   | dfsdfdsfds#  | fsdfsd+c   |
|      6 |      30 | 2015-11-16 | fdsfsd#    | dgdfg#fsdfsd | dfsd+      |
|      7 |      33 | 2015-11-16 | dfsdfds#   | dfgdfgfd#    | fdvgfdgdf+ |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

mysquery was:

```
select *, group_concat(trans_date) from all_trans where user_id=$user_id;
```

[my script link](http://pastebin.com/K8XihnKm)

but it is showing just a single transaction not all 5 transaction under a div.

I don't know what will be my query to show all transaction have same date in same div.

Any help will be kind for me.Thanks

Comment: my table have three columns row_id, user_id, trans_date, debit and credit and other column .

Comment: That query just give me one transaction out of 5 transaction

Comment: please see this link: http://pastebin.com/8ga0a72g

Comment: but in want like this:      date 2015-11-09 : all five reults show in a single div not in seperate

Comment: please see my expected result: http://pastebin.com/NRCsEbCZ

Comment: You need to update your query instead of `group_concat` simply use `group by trans_date` so your query will be look like as `select * from all_trans where user_id=$user_id group by trans_date` and then you need to work around on your array for such output

Comment: but it is showing just single transaction in two dates.  like: 2015-11-09 but have actually more than one transactiton

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query :

`select trans_date, group_concat(row_id, '&', user_id, '&', debit, '&', credit, '&', other SEPARATOR '|') AS rows_detail from all_trans where user_id=$user_id GROUP BY trans_date`

then, using PHP:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($insert)) 
{
    $rows = explode('|', $result['rows_detail']);

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
        list($row_id, $user_id, $debit, $credit, $other) = explode('&', $row, 5);
    }
}
```